# Center content vertically on Vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there a way to center content vertically in Vuetify?

With the `text-xs-center` helper class, the content gets centered horizontally only:

```html
<v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
  <v-layout row wrap>
     <v-flex xs12>
       Hello
     </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

From the [API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid-lists), I tested some other helper classes such as `align-content-center` but did not achieve the result.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

## Update for new vuetify version

In **v.2.x.x** , we can use [`align`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#align) and [`justify`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#justify). We have below options for setup the horizontal and vertical alignment.

1. PROPS **`align`** : `'start','center','end','baseline','stretch'`
2. PRPS **`justify`** : `'start','center','end','space-around','space-between'`

```html
<v-container fill-height fluid>
  <v-row align="center"
      justify="center">
      <v-col></v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

For more details please refer this [vuetify grid-system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/) and you could check here with working [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/bGNryEd) demo.

---

## Original answer

You could use [`align-center`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid-lists) for [`layout`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined#introduction) and `fill-height` for container.

**Demo with v1.x.x**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app' 
})
```

```css
.bg{
    background: gray;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
      <v-container bg fill-height grid-list-md text-xs-center>
        <v-layout row wrap align-center>
          <v-flex>
            Hello I am center to vertically using "align-center".
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want to add a note: `align-center` center works only if `fill-height` is set for the container. Thank you

Comment: I worth to mention that, in order to this to work, you have to use children of `<v-app>` directly. If you have some `<divs>`s as root of `v-footer|v-content`, this will fail (for example, if you're using layouts to reuse components as pages and you need a root `<div>` for your `<template>`).

Comment: Note that this is using the old grid system, the new one uses `v-row` and `v-col`. See the answer by Billal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089655/3315164

Comment: @nelson6e65 how exactly do you solve this? I can't center my v-flex :(

Comment: The `fill-height` was the missing part for me, it's not in the docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-container/. Upvoting, cheers guys!

Comment: When using multiple rows this seems to space the rows out evenly rather than putting them in the center vertically due to `flex: 1 1 100%` being applied to the rows when `fill-width` is used on the container

Answer (score 39):

In Vuetify 2.x, **v-layout** and **v-flex** are replaced by **v-row** and **v-col** respectively. To center the content both vertically and horizontally, we have to instruct the **v-row** component to do it:

```html
<v-container fill-height>
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
            Centered both vertically and horizontally
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</v-container>
```

- **align="center"** will center the content vertically **inside the row**
- **justify="center"** will center the content horizontally **inside the row**
- **fill-height** will center the whole content **compared to the page**.

Answer (score 9):

FOR CARDS: Concise and works in v2+.  This will get you a v-card with centered content HORIZONTALLY and VERTICALLY:

```html
<v-card class="d-flex align-center justify-center" min-height="250">
  Content here...
</v-card>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/res636611/pen/jOmGQGV)

Answer (score 8):

Still surprised that no one proposed the shortest solution with `align-center justify-center` to center content vertically and horizontally. Check [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-vue-vuetify-centering-ynosc) and code below:

```html
<v-container fluid fill-height>
  <v-layout align-center justify-center>
    <v-flex>
      <!-- Some HTML elements... -->
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's another approach using Vuetify `grid` system available in `Vuetify 2.x`: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids

```html
<v-container>
    <v-row align="center">
        Hello I am center to vertically using "grid".
    </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Comment: `justify` is for horizontal alignment and `align` is for vertical alignment. So you should have `align="center"` and not `justify="center"`

Answer (score 5):

For the new Vuetify v3.0.0.0-beta this worked for me:

```
<v-container class="fill-height">
    <v-row align="center" justify="center" class="fill-height">
        <p>Center</p>
    </v-row>
</v-container>
```

Comment: Just a little side note. Instead of align="center" you can also use align-content="center" in the v-row tag.

Answer (score 3):

`<v-container>` has to be **right after `<template>`**, if there is a `<div>` in between, the vertical align will just not work.

```html
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
      <v-row class="justify-center align-center">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
            Centered both vertically and horizontally
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Without using rows or columns... you can center your main content of your vuetify app like this:

```
<v-app>
    <v-main>
        <v-container fluid fill-height>
            <v-layout class="align-center justify-center">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
    </v-main>
</v-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my exemple the first v-for will take up all of the parent element's spacing, the fill-heigh will take up all the available height. This way we can use a second v-row to position as best as possible.

```
<v-row class="fill-height">
  <v-row align="center" justify="center">
    try TOO
    align="start" || align="center" ||  align="end" <br>
    justify="start" || justify="center" || justify="end"
  </v-row>
</v-row>
```

Plase check the grids docs here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#justify

Answer (score 1):

In Vuetify v2 you can achieve that with minimal markup using just the `d-flex`, `justify-center` and `align-center` classes on the container:

```
<div  
  style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black;"
  class="d-flex justify-center align-center"
>
  Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, `align="center"` was enough to center `FOO` vertically:

```
<v-row align="center">
  <v-col>FOO</v-col>
</row>
```